# how can I evaluate the unbalanced data set

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, pandas

The output here shows the titles and descriptions of the comments written for the evaluation of the top 100 books in amazon with nltk vader, and the total reviewer rating for those analyzes, but there is an imbalance between reviewer rating how can I statistically make sense of the data here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyO3d.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N5Cv.png

```
custrew[["reviewer rating","title sentiment result","desc sentiment result"]] \
    .groupby(["title sentiment result","desc sentiment result"]).sum()
```

code of output

```
def duygu_analizi(text):
    sentiment = analyzer.polarity_scores(text)
    if sentiment['compound'] >= 0.05:
        return 'Pozitif'
    elif sentiment['compound'] <= -0.05:
        return 'Negatif'
    else:
        return 'Nötr'

custrew["title sentiment result"] = custrew["review title"].apply(duygu_analizi)
```

example code for title sentiment result

also my data (ı dont show another columns because no necessary):
my goal is just define a relationship between title/description sentiement analysis and reviewer rating. when sentiment is positive, are reviewer ratings be positive too? or When sentiments are intense, does your rating also tend to be high?

ı have two distinct variable for title sentiment and description sentiment

[image: picture]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to analyze, and what problem does the imbalance present?

Comment: What is "title sentiment result" and "desc sentiment result"?  And what do you want to find out?

Comment: Hi @Dave, I would like to know if there is a high evaluation with emotional states with description emotion analysis with title emotion analysis

Comment: @PeterFlom title sentiment result and desc(description) sentiment results are result of sentiment analysis, I used nltk library's vader method for sentiment analysis

Comment: @VahşiBozkırlı Do you mean that you want to see how the sentiment score related to the title, and the sentiment score related to the description, both relates to the rating a reviewer gives? If so, is your question about what method to use for this purpose? Or do you already know the method you will use, but you think that "unbalanced data" might be a problem for this method?

Comment: -want to see how the sentiment score related to the title, and the sentiment score related to the description, both relates to the note a reviewer gives? If so, is your question about what method to use for this purpose- my question about what method to use for this purpose.

Comment: By the way, your code seems to transform a continuous variable (sentiment compound score) into a categorical variable (positive/negative sentiment). This is probably a mistake, depending on your ultimate goal with this analysis.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify what is the goal of the analysis, and that you want to know what method to use. Few people read comments, so you'll be more likely to get an answer by adding details directly in your original post.

Comment: reviewer rating is ordinal variable and ı convert to ordinal to nominal is this problem for statistical analysis?

Comment: Thresholding a continuous or ordinal scale is a terrible idea.  Analyze the rawest form of the data to preserve meaning and statistical power and precision.

Comment: You still do not mention what is your ultimate goal with the analysis you intend to do. The currently accepted answer seems to assume that you have 2 variables in your dataset. But from your question and comments, to me it looks like there are three variables in your dataset (title score, description score and reviewer rating. Am I correct?). You should really clarify your question, mention what is your goal here, and clarify the variables you have (the screenshot is quite confusing in this respect, and does not make it clear what your data is). Otherwise you may be going in a wrong direction.

Comment: my goal is just define a relationship between title/description sentiement analysis and reviewer rating. when sentiment is positive, are reviewer ratings be positive too? or  When sentiments are intense, does your rating also tend to be high?

Comment: @TunahanDeniz That makes your question much clearer. You should edit your question, and mention all this information directly in the original post, so more people will see it (few people read the comment section). Now, it's still unclear if you have two distinct variables for "title sentiment" and "description sentiment", or if you have a single one variable "sentiment". You should clarify that too.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of things you *could* do. Perhaps the simplest is chi-square of the table of the two ratings. There is clearly a strong relationship. The fact that the cells are not even roughly equal is not a problem here, as all of them are pretty big.

You could account for the ordinality of both by using a test such as Jonckheere-Terpstra rather than the usual chi-square.

If you think one of the ratings "depends' (loosely used) on the other, you could do ordinal logistic regression.

Or, you could look at the particular books where the ratings disagree.

And probably several other things; again, it depends on what you want to find out.